# CXF NullPointerException (not able to compile the webservice stubs on Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I'm generating webservice stubs using CXF and WSDL2JAVA, Everything runs fine on Eclipse, But when i deployed the war on Tomcat 7.0 running on Linux (OpenSuse). 

I'm getting the below error in catalina.out log file [the java files are not being compiled]:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:187)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ClassUtils.compile(ClassUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:306)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
```

**Eclipse Environment:**

- Eclipse version :Indigo
- JDK version :1.7.0_79
- Tomcat      :7
- cxf version :3.0.4

**OpenSuse Environment:**

- JDK version:1.7.0_79
- Tomcat     :7

WSDL2JAVA code:

```
WSDLToJava wsdlToJava = new WSDLToJava();
        ToolContext context=new ToolContext();
        wsdlToJava.setArguments(new String[]{"-d",tempDir,"-p","demopack","-verbose","-compile",wsdlURL});
        wsdlToJava.run(context);
```

Comment: Are you making SOAP calls from `main` in your Eclipse setup?  This sounds like a JAR is missing in your Tomcat deployment.

Comment: I'm generating SOAP webservice client stubs using WSDL2JAVA [using -compile option], the java files are generated but throws error while compiling.

Comment: These stubs are generated dynamically and stored in temp directory, and are not available in the WAR file

Comment: How are you running in Eclipse?  Please check your the `lib` folder in your WAR file by hand to make sure the stubs are where you think they are.  If the stubs are being deployed incorrectly, that could explain a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I checked it once again, they are no stub classes in `lib` folder, instead they are generated in `/var/cache/tomcat/temp` as intended.

Comment: OK...can you verify that the namespace you use in your Java code matches the path in the Tomcat folder?

Answer (score 1):

wsdl2java needs a compiler instance to generate and compile the stub class files.
So, I resolved the issue by resetting the PATH variable point to JDK/bin directory instead of JRE/bin.

Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Talend Open Studio tWebService component

```
Exception in component tWebService_1
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:187)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:141)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:136)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.compileJavaSrc(DynamicClientFactory.java:611)
```

Issue was SOLVED by adding  "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/:" to the start of PATH environmental variable in Linux.

```
echo $PATH   
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

P.S. While looking for solution i also uninstalled open-jdk and installed the one from Oracle via an prm package. Most likely this solution will work with open-jdk as well. 
Most complicated for me was locating the right jdk java binary file since i am not so good with Linux.

P.P.S. Same thing is true for Windows, Talend Open Studion has a separate parameter - need to set it to JDK java.exe

Window -> Preferences -> Talend : Java Interpreter

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe
```